# Header-Footer (text and background-image) positioning issues

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr, report, eso-pic

I'm working on the header and footer section (which are supposed to appear on every page). I've looked around already but I haven't managed to find any answers close to what I need. I'm trying, but failing to:

1. Make the blue line (that already appears at the very bottom of the page), to also appear at the very top of the page (above the header's image).
2. Make the background-image in the header stretch to fully cover the pagewidth. I also want to increase the height of the image a bit, so the text does not appear so squished and so close to the top-edge of the page.
3. Make the text, which is on top of the header image, to start on the far left of the page (instead of being centered like now), but the page-number to appear on the far right. I want the same alignment for the text and page-number in the footer (which currently it doesn't even appear).

Can someone help me with the above please? (and also help me understand my errors by explaing to me why my code doesn't work accordingly atm)

Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperheight=20cm,paperwidth=26cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{highlight_colour}{HTML}{067dac}
\definecolor{secondary_colour}{HTML}{34545c}

% ==============================================
% HEADER AND FOOTER 
% ==============================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}

\chead{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{header_design02.PNG}};
        \draw (0, 0) node {
            \color{secondary_colour}\footnotesize
            Some text
            \hspace{0.5cm}
            /
            \hspace{0.5cm}
            Some other text
            \hspace{0.5cm}
            /
            \hspace{0.5cm}
            Yet another piece of text
            \hfill\thepage
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\cfoot{
    {\color{secondary_colour}\footnotesize
        Some text
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        /
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        Some other text
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        /
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        Yet another piece of text
        \hfill\thepage
    }
}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{{\color{highlight_colour}\rule{\paperwidth}{5pt}}}} % bottom line

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{{\color{highlight_colour}\rule{\paperwidth}{5pt}}}} % bottom line

% ==============================================

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Here's the header background-image I used:

[image]

And here is my current output:

[image]

Comment: For the rule at the very top of the page, use the optional argument of `\rule`, like this: `\rule[-5pt]{\paperwidth}{5pt}`.

Comment: That's great, thanks @Bernard (this has solved #1)! I've also managed to figure out the problem with #3 - the issue was with the margins, they pushed the footer out of the page somehow - which i managed to resolve using \vspace. So unless someone has a better solution for that, I consider #3 solved too.

Comment: The only problem remaining now to be solved is #2, which no matter if I use scale or width for the tikz node, the image seems to find a wall on the left-hand side and not moving past it (to cover the entire pagewidth). Any ideas?

Comment: For the header background, if it is the same for all pages, I would use again `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{[\includegraphics{…}}` as for the blue rules. You might insert the background within the same command, a bit below the rule.

Comment: Ah I was ready to update you that I've solved it, I basically did what you have suggested now too :D I had to also use \raisebox for it to work. This is what worked: \AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-1.3cm}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=1.2cm]{header_design02.PNG}}}}

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help and time @Bernard! All raised points are now resolved :D If you would like to summarise all of the above in one answer, I would be happy to accept it :)

Comment: If you are going to put a tikzpicture inside a fancyhdr, you should use [overlay].  The origin will be located at the baseline-center  (uising \chead) of the header.

Comment: Thank you @John Kormylo, I'll look into that too :)